# ggplot reorder geombar from down to up

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a ggplot graph and I want it to show the data from down to up. I know how to reorder based on the the number of entry but not in another way. Those are dates used as factor.

This is a normal graph

```
x <- ggplot(data, aes(y = factor(date), fill=category)) 
y<- x+geom_bar()+ggtitle("Number of articles per date")+
  labs(y = "date", fill = "category")
print(y)
```

This is what I tried with no effect:

```
data %>% arrange(date) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = factor(date), fill=category))+
geom_bar()+ggtitle("Number of articles per date")+
  labs(y = "date", fill = "category")
```

Perhaps there is a way to use the column "date" as as.Date() but I don't know how to use the count of entry per date with as.Date.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data, so I made up some:

```
dates <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-1"), as.Date("2001-01-12"), by = "day")
set.seed(123)
data <- data.frame(date = sample(dates, 200, replace = TRUE),
                 category = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 200, replace = TRUE))
```

If I understand your question correctly, you want the earliest date at the bottom? You can do that by added a `scale_y_discrete` and setting the breaks as the reverse of the level of the factor:

```
y + scale_y_discrete(breaks = rev(levels(factor(data$date))))
```

[image]

If you want the earliest date at the bottom, then do not reverse the levels. Use one of the following:

```
y + scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(factor(data$date)))
y + scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(factor(data$date))))
```

Comment: If you want the earliest date on top, then remove the `rev` and use `scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(factor(data$date)))`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Actually, I want the earliest date on top, that seems more logical, what do you think? On mine it shows down.
Ok, based on your answer I tried this: 
````
scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(factor(data$date))))
````

But I don't fully understand it. Why do we need the levels? The documentation for scale_y_discrete() does not mention reverse (I think). And also, why "breaks = ..." does not work but "limits= ..." work?

The data can be found here: [ https://github.com/Alqua/nCovMemory/blob/master/data/data.csv ]

Comment: somehow 
```
scale_y_discrete(breaks = levels(factor(data$date)))
```
does not work on my data. It appears with the earliest date down. No idea why.

Comment: Do you mind to add: `scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(levels(factor(data$date))))`
to your answer?
I could then mark it as correct!
Thanks again